# tensorflow-TypeError: Input 'x' of 'LogicalAnd' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of bool

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two tf arrays of float32, I am taking logical_and operation between the two arrays

`tf.math.logical_and(b, a)`

Here, I got the error - `TypeError: Input 'x' of 'LogicalAnd' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of bool.`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tensors `a` and `b` need to be boolean tensors if you plan to use `tf.math.logical_and`. Check the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/logical_and). This will **not** work:

```py
import tensorflow as tf 

a = tf.constant([5,4,3,2], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.constant([5,6,7,8], dtype=tf.float32)
c = tf.math.logical_and(b, a)
```

Something like this will work:

```py
import tensorflow as tf 

a = tf.constant([5,4,3,2], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.constant([5,6,7,8], dtype=tf.float32)

a = tf.cast(tf.boolean_mask(a, [True, False, True, False]), dtype=tf.bool)
b = tf.cast(tf.boolean_mask(b, [True, False, True, False]), dtype=tf.bool)

print(tf.math.logical_and(b, a))
```

Just make sure the tensors are booleans.